# Is there any tool that can analyze my PHP 5.3 source code and give me a list of things to fix to migrate to PHP 5.6?

Tags: static-analysis, php-5.3, php-5.6

I'm trying to find the safest way to go from 5.3 to 5.6 for a very large codebase. Doing everything manually will take a long time. Are there any tools that can analyze code statically and give a list of absolute minimum changes needed to go to 5.6?

Comment: Asking for software is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Comment: Closers: rather than just slam such questions closed, you could at least tell OP about "Software Recommendations", where such questions are explicitly ON-TOPIC.  See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: How do you define a "long time" and how much do you expect it to cost?